# lag using R programming.

Tags: r, lag, dplyr

Please help me in getting this lag logic for the price column for each class. 
this is just the sample data, there will be many rows in each airline, 2 airlines will not have the same number of rows.

input table. 
QR - quarter
AL - Airline
CL - CLass

```
QR  AL  Cl      Price
1   EM  First   10000
2   EM  First   10000
3   EM  First   10000
4   EM  First   10000
1   EM  Second  8000
2   EM  Second  8000
3   EM  Second  8000
4   EM  Second  8000
1   EM  Third   6000
2   EM  Third   6000
3   EM  Third   6000
4   EM  Third   6000
1   BA  First   10000
2   BA  First   10000
3   BA  First   10000
4   BA  First   10000
5   BA  First   10000
6   BA  First   10000
1   BA  Second  8000
2   BA  Second  8000
3   BA  Second  8000
4   BA  Second  8000
5   BA  Second  8000
6   BA  Second  8000
1   BA  Third   6000
2   BA  Third   6000
3   BA  Third   6000
4   BA  Third   6000
5   BA  Third   6000
6   BA  Third   6000
```

output table - I need to DF as below: 
First DF - the price will have a lag of 2 cells for each class.

```
QR  AL  CL  Price
1   EM  First   NA
2   EM  First   NA
3   EM  First   10000
4   EM  First   10000
1   EM  Second  NA
2   EM  Second  NA
3   EM  Second  8000
4   EM  Second  8000
1   EM  Third   NA
2   EM  Third   NA
3   EM  Third   6000
4   EM  Third   6000
```

Second DF: the price will have a lag of 4 cells for each class.

```
QR  AL  CL      Price
1   BA  First   NA
2   BA  First   NA
3   BA  First   NA
4   BA  First   NA
5   BA  First   10000
6   BA  First   10000
1   BA  Second  NA
2   BA  Second  NA
3   BA  Second  NA
4   BA  Second  NA
5   BA  Second  8000
6   BA  Second  8000
1   BA  Third   NA
2   BA  Third   NA
3   BA  Third   NA
4   BA  Third   NA
5   BA  Third   6000
6   BA  Third   6000
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite understand what you want to do. The second data.frame looks to me like the first with the first two rows of each airline  and class combination level replaced by NA. So if thats what you want you can just use dplyr (function ddply), split on the variables "AL" and "CL" (.variables = c("AL","CL") and use function(x) x$Price[1:2] = "NA".

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't quite understand what you want to do.
The second data.frame looks to me like the first with the first two rows of each airline and class combination level replaced by NA.
So if thats what you want you can just use plyr (function ddply), split on the variables "AL" and "CL" (.variables = c("AL","CL") and use function(x) x$Price[1:2] = "NA". – user18093 34 secs ago    edit

Without trying this should work: (haven't used ddply in a while, so some details might be wrong)

```
ddply(df, .variables = .(AL,CL), .function = function(subset){
                                      new_price = subset$price
                                      new_price[1:2] = "NA"
                                      subset$price = new_price
```

My function is written to make it clear what is done - you can just type subset$price[1:2] = "NA" if you feel like it.

For the second data.frame: Do the same ddply, just use a different .function - you can figure it out yourself I hope